# When was this Lego Adventurers T-Shirt produced?

Tags: set-identification, apparel

When was this Lego Adventurers T-Shirt produced, and what is its model number?

The link says 1998. Is it correct? And where can I see the full design?

https://www.ebay.com/itm/352740773574

[image] [image]

Answer (score 5):

The shirt itself says 1998 on it, which coincides with the earliest known release of a set for that theme.

[image]

Here it is advertised on/in this 1999 January/February issue of Lego Mania magazine:

[image]
(https://www.flickr.com/photos/timlydy/22805063335/in/photostream/)

Given this was advertised at the very beginning of 1999, I think it is safe to assume that 1998 is the correct date for when the T-shirt and Magazine were printed. As for a model number, as Alexander O'Mara mentioned, it's listed on Bricklink as TS10.  I am not familiar with model numbers for Lego clothing, or if they even have them.  Bricklink has likely created their own format for designating a number to a particular design to simplify and clarify it's identification for buyers and sellers.

Answer (score 4):

## Year:

Probably 1999.

[The Jungle Adventurers sets were released in 1999](https://brickset.com/sets/theme-Adventurers/subtheme-Jungle), and it seems likely that it would be released that same year. The full design below shows this is the Adventurers line it corresponds to.

There is a copyright on the design, which turns out to be 1998, but it likely predates the actual release which seems to have been in January 1999.

## Model Number:

Unclear if it really has one.

[BrickLink lists it as TS10](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?G=TS10).

## Design:

[image]

(source: [BrickLink](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?G=TS10))

[image]

(source: [Grailed](https://www.grailed.com/listings/8393422-lego-x-vintage-vintage-lego-jungle-adventures-olive-green-t-shirt))

[image]

(source: [Grailed](https://www.grailed.com/listings/8393422-lego-x-vintage-vintage-lego-jungle-adventures-olive-green-t-shirt))

Comment: These pictures are a great find, you should consider adding one in the form of an edit to the question for clarity.

Comment: I noticed you edited-in the 1998 info after I posted my answer :P